# how to include .CSS .JS files when using from MVC pattern ( RewriteEngine )

Tags: php, css, model-view-controller

I am using a MVC pattern but i have a problem. when we are using this RewriteEngine :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]

</IfModule>
```

However when using :

```
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

This will rewrite to a new pattern and its problem for template .
Please give me a good method for use . And good method for useng white XAMPP.

Thans

Comment: # Allow asset folders through
`RewriteRule ^((.+)?/assets/(.+)) - [L]`

untested but "should" work

Comment: @JamesLalor Thanks but it dosn't work .

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(assets/(.+)) - [L]`

Answer (score 0):

Should add in this line:

```
RewriteRule ^(assets/(.+)) - [L]
```

And in this order:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(assets/(.+)) - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]
```